# Syntax of inserting array elements to database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

This isn't anything overly complicated (I assume), I'm just not sure of the syntax for doing what I want. I'm trying to insert a value from an array into the database. Below achieves what I want to do, however I was wondering if it could be reformatted to the code below that.

***Current code which does what I want:***

```
$name = explode(" ",$fullName);
$firstName = $name[0];  
$lastName = $name[count($name) - 1];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `person` VALUES(NULL, '$firstName', '$lastName',0)"));
```

***What I want to know is if it can be formatted like this:***

```
$name = explode(" ",$fullName);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `person` VALUES(NULL, '$name[0]', '$name[count($name) - 1]',0)"));
```

I tried this earlier a few different ways and got an error, is it just an issue with syntax or is it something a bit deeper?

Oh, and I should add that the only time I actually got the insert to run fully, I ended up with `Array[0]` and `Array[2] - 1` in the `first_name` and `last_name` columns respectively.

Thanks all, hopefully I've been clear enough. Need any more info, let me know.

Comment: `$name = explode(" ",$fullName);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'person' VALUES(NULL, '$name[0]', '$name[count($name) - 1]');` This code fetched an error?? What was the error? Formatting looks fine.

Comment: @RubyLovely Am I being stupid or is that not what I already did?

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO person VALUES(NULL, '$name[0]', '".($name[count($name) - 1])."')");` more like this ..

Comment: @dbf Yeah just noticed that, must've typoed. Corrected it (I hadn't typoed in my actual PHP).

Comment: @Zackehh9lives hmm, didn't correct any typo, look at the difference again ;)

Comment: @dbf Just noticed that! It works :) Put it as an answer since you got there first?

Comment: @Zackehh9lives nah it's ok, didn't post as an answer but as a comment, so pick the one answering it first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `person` VALUES(NULL, '$name[0]', '".$name[count($name) - 1]."' ");
```

Comment: Please don't use chat speak on Stack Overflow. Take the time to write "you" instead of "u".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$name = explode(" ",$fullName); 
$query="INSERT INTO person VALUES(NULL,'". $name[0]."','".$name[count($name) - 1]."'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `person` VALUES(NULL, '{$name[0]}', '{$name[count($name) - 1]}',0)");
```